# ¿Cómo elevar los privilegios de un usuario solo cuando sea necesario? (UAC) - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, permisos

Estoy trabajando con un actualizador automático para mi sistema, me basé en este proyecto de muestra de github [SharpUpdate](https://github.com/henryxrl/SharpUpdate) a la cual le he hecho algunas modificaciones a mi gusto...

Estoy enfrentando un problema el cual es, que al momento de descargar archivos del servidor, si deseo modificar y escribir en una carpeta a la que el usuario no tiene acceso, el proceso fallará, a menos que manualmente se le otorgen permisos al usuario para modificar en dicha carpeta...

```
File.Move("origen", $"{Destino}.bak");
...
File.Delete(...);
```

Entonces como podría mostrar el **Control de cuentas de usuario (UAC)** para que se pueda colocar la clave de un usuario administrador para ejecutar el proceso?, algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo, para validar si el usuario tiene el acceso requerido a la carpeta, hago lo siguiente:

```
public static bool DirectoryHasPermission(string directorio, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights tipoAcceso)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(directorio)) return false;
    try
    {
        System.Security.AccessControl.AuthorizationRuleCollection reglas = Directory.GetAccessControl(directorio).GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier));
        System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity identity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        foreach (System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule regla in reglas)
        {
            if (identity.Groups.Contains(regla.IdentityReference))
            {
                if ((tipoAcceso & regla.FileSystemRights) == tipoAcceso)
                {
                    if (regla.AccessControlType == System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow)
                        return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
    return false;
}
```

Para usarlo así:

```
//if (!DirectoryHasPermission(@"C:\Users\xxxx\miCarpeta", System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Modify))
if (!DirectoryHasPermission(@"C:\Users\xxxx\miCarpeta", System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.FullControl))
{
     ///Mostrar la pantalla para colocar el password del usuario administrador...
     ///Realizar la operación con los privilegios necesarios, aunque sea en un proceso separado
}
else
{
    ///Continua el proceso normal....
}
```

---

Leyendo he investigando encontré lo siguiente:

```
Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

Que ejecutará el proceso como administrador para hacer lo que necesite con el registro, pero esta manera, no solicita al usuario un cuadro de diálogo UAC.

Tambíen esto de agregar un manifiesto de la aplicación que le indique a Windows que ejecute la aplicación  de forma elevada, pero esto ejecutará la aplicación así todo el tiempo y esta no es la idea...

```
<requestedExecutionLevel
 level="asInvoker|highestAvailable|requireAdministrator"
uiAccess="true|false"/>
```

Para no extender más esta pregunta, lo más cercano a lo que busco es este código de ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49115285/8933039 Pero por ejemplo probando en W10, veo que solo muestra el cuadro de dialogo de "Si" y "No", pero no se solicita una clave para usar el proceso con un usuario con permisos administrativos con el UAC... Si a alguno de ustedes tiene conocimiento al respecto, favor guiarme a una solución.

Entorno de Desarrollo Visual Studio C#, .NetFramework 4.5.2

**Nota:** Me diculpo por ampliar tanto la pregunta, es una forma de que sea un poco más entendible